# Having trouble with some lists on python

Tags: python, list, loops, input, while-loop

```
def main():
    num_list = []
    n = input('Your favorite number: ')

    again = 'g'

    while again == 'g':
        value = float(input('Enter a number: '))
        if value > n:
            num_list.append(value)
        print ('Would you like to enter another number?: ')
        again = input('y=yes, n=no')
main()
```

Here's my code. The > isn't working, what do i do?

Comment: When getting the value for `value` you convert it to `float`. Why don't you do the same with `n`?

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with your code,

1. As comments says, your comparing a `float` type to a `str`. Note that it is possible in Python 2 to compare mixed types for nonsensical answers, not in Python 3.
2. You're comparing your `again` variable against 'g' only. which is clearly not what you want. Try this code :

   ```
   def main():
       num_list = []
       n = input('Your favorite number: ')

       again = 'g'
       while again in {'g','y'} :
           value = float(input('Enter a number: '))
           if value > float(n):
               num_list.append(value)
           print ('Would you like to enter another number?: ')
           again = input('y=yes, n=no')
   main()
   ```

Comment: Good point, I'll remove the statement since it is not relevant anyway. Thank you for the insight !